# How to pass a captured value (handle) from {% raw %} to get a object from shopify in liquid?

Tags: shopify, vuejs3, liquid, shopify-template

I'm using vue3 and liquid for some Shopify theme developments.In my case, there is a value from vue component and I want to use this value to get a shopify object within liquid file.

```
<div v-for="handle in featuredHandlesArray" :key="handle" >            
  {% capture article_liquid %}
    {% raw %}{{ handle }}{% endraw %}
  {% endcapture %}

  {% assign article_obj = articles[article_liquid] %}
</div>
```

Here I'm getting above 'featuredHandlesArray' from vue component and looping with a v-for. There's no issue with it. If I echo these 'handle' value in the loop, it prints my relevant handle. Even when I echo captured 'article_liquid' variable below the '{% endcapture %}' tag, it prints too. But when I try to pass that handle to get the article object from shopify, it's nothing. It means 'articles[article_liquid]' is not working. I just want to get that article object from shopify by passing handle and assign that object into a variable like 'article_obj'.

If anyone experienced this kind of issue, please give me a support. Or any suggestion will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue, but just to eliminate a possible culprit, how does the final html look like?

Comment: If I understood Liquid syntax correctly, the article_liquid variable will look like this: "{{ handle }}" because of the [{% raw %}](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/template/) tag, so try to remove that raw tag